# Update column based on sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

My current table structure is 12 column, each representing month.

I need to dynamically select which column to update based on sysdate.

for updation done in january, the query should look like :-

```
UPDATE report SET jan VALUE = 'blabla'
```

and for updation done in december, the query should look like :-

```
UPDATE report SET dec VALUE = 'blabla'
```

Is there any way to simplify this. Maybe into something like this:-

```
UPDATE report SET curMonth() VALUE = 'blabla'
```

Comment: what flavor of database is this?

Comment: I'd have to columns - value and DATE.  If you want a 12 column result, broken down by month -- use a PIVOT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table that has 12 columns with the names of the 12 months is a poor design-- it violates basic normalization and creates problems like this where you have to resort to using dynamic SQL.  If you had a properly normalized table with one row per month, you could write a simple static SQL statement.

You could do something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_value( p_value IN varchar2 )
AS
  l_month_num integer :=  to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'mm' )) ;
BEGIN
  IF( l_month_num = 1 )
  THEN
    UPDATE report
       SET jan = p_value;
  ELSIF( l_month_num = 2 )
  THEN
    UPDATE report
       SET feb = p_alue;
  ELSIF 
  ...
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thx, Justin. If I understand correctly, yours is to create a CASE statement for each month resulting in 12 different queries.

I understand that this is a poor design but this is adhoc project where every logic was done in database. Programming language simply display the output without much work done.

Comment: @ZaimanNoris - Yes, my suggestion is to create a `CASE` statement (or a series of `IF` statements-- whatever works better for you) in order to generate 12 different queries.  You'd be better off refactoring the table and writing a view that pivots the data but if you don't want to change the schema, 12 queries would likely be the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of database are you using ? You can do this easily by using procedures (if your database supports them).

**(Update from comments)**

Example based on http://mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedures-hello-world-examples

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateMonth( month IN NUMBER ) 
IS 
BEGIN 
     CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN 
              Update report SET jan VALUE = "blalala" 
          WHEN month = 2 THEN 
              Update report SET feb VALUE = "blalala" ... 
     END CASE; 
END;
```

Comment: Forget to mention. It is running on Oracle 10g.

Comment: I think then your job will be easy write a procedure to get the input parameter as month number . Then inside procedure you can write the your sql query dynamically according to month number. SO you only have to call the stored procedure with the parameter

Comment: Example : -   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateMonth(month IN NUMBER) IS BEGIN CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN Update report SET jan VALUE = "blalala" WHEN month = 2 THEN Update report SET feb VALUE = "blalala" ... END CASE; END; /                                                http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedures-hello-world-examples/

Comment: Updated response to include code from comments for better readabilty.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define a function SetValue(columnName,columnValue);

```
SetValue(columnMonth,columnValue, newValue)
{
    // firstly, get the month number from systemData
    var curMonth = xxx;    
    // secondary, compare columnMonth and the month number from systemData
    if (columnMonth == curMonth){
       return newValue;
    }
    else{
       return columnValue;
    }
}
```

and then, write below sql:

```
Update report SET jan VALUE = SetValue(1, jan, "blalala"), feb VALUE=SetValue(2,feb,"blalala") ....;
```

Comment: The variable here is the column name (curMonth) not the value it self.
It should update only one column (current month)